# Корзина woocommerce и мелкие проблемы

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, cms, woocommerce

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собрал из модулей магазин с использованием woocommerce и saphali русификатора.
1. Проблема с дублированием кнопки "Перейти к оплате".
2. Дублирование блока "Сумма в корзине"
3. Некорректный перевод страницы.(Искал в saphali словарях .po/.mo там искомых фраз не найдено.)

Можете помочь в плане куда копать поиск по страницам с кодом не дал особых результатов и изменения приводят к тому что страница становится пустая.

Comment: Посмотрите в выводе на странице корзины. (woocommerce->templates-> card)

Comment: изменение php кода в страницах на сайте .ведет к прекращению отображения вообще. Я тож думаю дайка тупо исходник подправлю

Comment: сам вывод посмотрите( там где по идее выставляется приоритет хуков)

Comment: страницы корзины в принципе не бывает, она собирается шаблон+ php станицы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того чтобы спокойно править шаблоны Woocommerce, не изменяя код в самом плагине, нужно скопировать содержымое папки

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates
```

в папку вашей темы

```
/wp-content/themes/ваша_тема/woocommerce
```

Шаблон корзины:

```
/wp-content/themes/ваша_тема/woocommerce/cart/cart.php
```

Блок "Сумма в корзине" повешен на хук

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' ); ?>
```

или может выводиться функцией:

```
<?php woocommerce_cart_totals(); ?>
```

Посмотрите может в вашей теме уже есть шаблоны woocommerce и вних продублирован етот код, или нужно искать где продублирован хук 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals'

Comment: спасибо, за развернутый ответ.  да действительно тема создала дубликат страниц корзины. Поиском по кючевым словам прошелся по пути 2-ых исходников и методом удаления и просмотра что же изменилось решил проблему. но вы на вопрос ответили)

Answer (score 0):

Также столкнулся с тем что после обновления Woocommerce задвоились кнопки в корзине.
Тема Sommerce.
Решил так:
1. В Woocommerce -> состояние системы -> Шаблоны было видно несоответствие версий файлов.
2. Скачал свежую версию  Woocommerce отсюда: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/tree/2.3.8
3. Заменил в /wp-content/themes/ваша_тема/woocommerce отмеченные в п.1 файлы.

з.ы. "двойная кнопка" ушла после замены файла cart.php
з.ы.ы. файл pagination.php вернул старый - это номера страниц товара